# Inserting a character to the start of each line in a HTML Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, replace

So over the past few days I have been searching for a solution that will allow me to insert a character (Specifically, the dollar sign) at the beginning of each line within a div. This is so that I can type the the commands in the back end with out the dollar sign and have it inserted automatically.

Currently, the backend of the site is using WordPress with the custom shortcode [command]. When the site is loaded the commands are returned as such:

```
<div id="command">
    First Command<br />
    Second Command<br />
    Last Command<br />
</div>
```

I have tried to use JavaScript to replace '`<br />`' tag with '`<br />&dollar;`' however it doesn't replace all of them.

Any help is appreciated.
Cheers,
Joe

Comment: Makes more sense to do a ul and then have li:before with the dollar sign.

Comment: @Aibrean I may have to if I can't find a way to do it but I was trying to avoid going through the posts that use commands and changing them if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple same ids:

```
$(function() {
 var textNodes = $("[id^=command]");
  $.each(textNodes, function(index, value) {
    var nodes = $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3;
    });
    $.each(nodes,function(index, value) {
      if(index!=nodes.length-1)   $(this).before("&dollar;");
    });

  });
});
```

**[Example : DEMO](http://jsbin.com/suxuha/3/edit)**

```
$(function() {
 var textNodes = $("#command").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
  })
$.each(textNodes,function(index, value) {
  if(index!=textNodes.length-1) $(this).before("&dollar;");
});
});
```

**Output:**

```
$ First Command
$ Second Command
$ Last Command
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/suxuha/2/edit)**

Comment: The code is working perfectly for the first div. Is it possible to make the code work for all of the command div's in the page?

Comment: Yes... Can you replace id with class.. Then it will work fine.. There is another trick to make multiple ids with same value to work but it's against html standards.. Because ids need to be unique..

Comment: In case you can't make changes to the html let me know.. I will update my answer for multiple ids..

Comment: Thanks for all of the help with this! I have updated the HTML to use class instead of ID but the code may help some one in the future. @mohamedrias Thanks for the lesson about the ID's being unique, didn't realize until today. Answer Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing with regular expressions. It is possible that some breaks don't contain a slash or a space and I think this is why you might have missed some.

```
var str = str.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/ig, "<br />&dollar;");
```

The parameter `g` makes sure all occurrences are replaced in the string. The parameter `i` makes the search not case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
var textLines = ($('#command').html()).split('<br>');
var newLines = $.map(textLines,function(line){
    return '&dollar;' + line;
});
$('#command').html(newLines.join('<br>'))
```

output

```
$ First Command
$ Second Command
$ Last Command
$
```